# Geary not installing

Tags: dependencies, geary, email-client

I have a problem that Geary is not installing even after repeated attempts. The below is the error I am getting. Please let me know what is the corrective measures Thanks!

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 geary : Depends: libgee-0.8-2 (>= 0.14.0) but 0.10.5-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: While it does not apply a 100% it still should provides solutions for unmet dependencies: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install following ppa: https://launchpad.net/~vala-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vala-team/ppa
```

then perform an update and upgrade

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

after that, just install geary (from the daily ppa)

```
sudo apt-get install geary
```